# JMeter: Test validation

Tags: validation, jmeter

I need to create test which do the following

1. Go through the wizard fill some
   forms (submitting each of them)
2. Extract from the final page some data
3. Using extracted data
4. make an SQL request to database
   based on request result test is
   qualified as FAILED or SUCCEEDED etc.
   (it can be simple SQL query
     SELECT count(id) from ... where ...)

I would appreciate if any body has an experience with JMeter and can tell me

- it is possible to do with JMeter
- give me main hints on how to do it
- about other suitable performance test tools for this task if this is not possible (or not easy) with JMeter

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in JMeter.

The easiest way is to record filling out the wizard and then modifying the script. It would look like this:

Thread Group

- HTTP REQUEST - fill out form

-- Post Process Regular Expression to extract Data

- SQL Request using extracted data

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf